# Please, Sir, I Want Some More!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I was reading the classic [Oliver Twist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Twist) last night and I came across the famous quote in which Oliver says;

> Please, sir, I want some more.

I ended up writing a rather simple riddle related to this. I hope you all enjoy it, and as a secondary question; if you're a reader, who is your favorite author? Mine happens to be [Jules Verne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Verne), and obviously his most popular work [20,000 Leagues Under the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Thousand_Leagues_Under_the_Sea) is my favorite.

So without further ado:

> Desperate times call for desperate measures;
>
> Sometimes they're met, with hidden treasures.
>
> In order to find me you won't have to ask;
>
> Nor should you beg, to finish your task.
>
> You don't need to sing, though I'm found in a hymn;
>
> You just need to look, for my synonyms.

What word am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a

> Prayer?

Desperate times call for desperate measures;

> People bargain with God through praying.

Sometimes they're met, with hidden treasures.

> Praying may bring miracles (especially when used as a trope in fiction).

In order to find me you won't have to ask;

> You don't ask people if you can pray or not. It's a right.

Nor should you beg, to finish your task.

> You can beg in a prayer, but that's not really what it's for.

You don't need to sing, though I'm found in a hymn;

> Hymns are psalms or prayers.

You just need to look, for my synonyms.

> Begging is a synonym of prayer. People plea in desperate times.

As for the title

> Oliver is essentially praying for more food.

As for books, my favorite author is Brandon Sanderson, with the Stormlight Archive being my favorite series of books (well, the cosmere in general).

Comment: This was a great find, I originally wanted to go with *implore*, but it didn't seem to fit the story all together.